# Android Up Indicator Icon

Tags: android

This may be silly but I've been looking over an hour for the **Up Indicator** icon so I can customize it in my image editor tool. Where can I find that icon? It is not in the **Android Design Icon Pack**, as I just searched in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SDK installed on your device, you can find the icon in `%SDK-FOLDER%/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable-*/ic_ab_back_holo_light_am` . You can take from there and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer called out that the icon exists in Android by default and that it does not to be manually added.

But this did not address the question as asked.

You should be able to get the icon from the Android libraries themselves, or from Google material design icon back available here (https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=arrow_back&style=baseline)

Comment: Not a criticism, but a curiosity, have any other apps used colorized up icons?

Comment: Well I'm actually using the white one. It may be the default for Dark theme, but I'm using light theme cause I'm changing the color to the action bar only, same as Play Music app

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

It has many other icons not only the up button. You can also change the icon color if you want.